# how to insert data in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

> I have a project that relates to sqlite. when I add data, application force close. I've been able to add data to sqlite through the code, but I have difficulties when adding data through the form. I experienced the app force close, what can anybody help me?
>
> This my code
>
> PemainDbAdapter.java

```
public class PemainDbAdapter {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NIM = "nim";
public static final String KEY_NAMA = "nama";
public static final String KEY_JURUSAN = "jurusan";
public static final String KEY_TELP = "no_telp";
public static final String KEY_UMUR = "umur";
public static final String TAG = "CountriesDbAdapter";
public DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
public SQLiteDatabase mDb;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mvp";
public static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "daftar_pemain";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public final Context mCtx;
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
                KEY_NIM + "," +
                KEY_NAMA + "," +
                KEY_JURUSAN + "," +
                KEY_TELP + "," +
                KEY_UMUR + "," +
                " UNIQUE (" + KEY_NIM +"));";
public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
public PemainDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}
public PemainDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close() {
    if (mDbHelper != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}
public long createPemain(String nim, String nama, String jurusan, String no_telp, String umur) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NIM, nim);
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAMA, nama);
    initialValues.put(KEY_JURUSAN, jurusan);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TELP, no_telp);
    initialValues.put(KEY_UMUR, umur);
    return mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
public boolean deleteAllPemain() {
    int doneDelete = 0;
    doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, null , null);
    Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
    return doneDelete > 0;
}
public Cursor fetchPemainByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
    Log.w(TAG, inputText);
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
        mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_NIM, KEY_NAMA, KEY_JURUSAN, KEY_TELP, KEY_UMUR},
                null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    else {
        mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_NIM, KEY_NAMA, KEY_JURUSAN, KEY_TELP, KEY_UMUR},
                KEY_NAMA + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
                null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
public Cursor fetchAllPemain() {
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                    KEY_NIM, KEY_NAMA, KEY_JURUSAN, KEY_TELP, KEY_UMUR},
            null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
public void insertSomePemain() {
    createPemain("125410011", "Adi Saputra", "Teknik Informstika", "081904445501", "20 Tahun");
    createPemain("125410012", "Mukti Setyawan", "Teknik Informatika", "081904445502", "19 Tahun");
    createPemain("125410013", "Titit", "Siatem Informasi", "081904445503", "21 Tahun");

}
```

> Input_Pemain.java

```
public class Input_Pemain extends Activity {
public PemainDbAdapter dbHelper;
private EditText editTextNim, editTextNama, editTextJurusan, editTextTelepon, editTextUmur;
private Button btnInput;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input__pemain);

    this.editTextNim = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editNIM);
    this.editTextNama = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editNama);
    this.editTextJurusan = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editJurusan);
    this.editTextTelepon = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editTelepon);
    this.editTextUmur = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editUmur);
    this.btnInput = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnInput);

    btnInput.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String nim = editTextNim.getText().toString().trim();
            String nama = editTextNama.getText().toString().trim();
            String jurusan = editTextJurusan.getText().toString().trim();
            String no_telp = editTextTelepon.getText().toString().trim();
            String umur = editTextUmur.getText().toString().trim();

            if(nim.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tolong masukan data lengkap!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(nama.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tolong masukan data lengkap!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(jurusan.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tolong masukan data lengkap!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(no_telp.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tolong masukan data lengkap!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(umur.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tolong masukan data lengkap!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                dbHelper = new PemainDbAdapter(Input_Pemain.this);
                dbHelper.createPemain(nim, nama, jurusan, no_telp, umur);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

> Help me please!

Comment: Your application force closed, share the stacktrace!

Comment: How to? sorry i beginners here @0xDEADC0DE

Comment: Somewhere in Android Studio or Eclipse you have a window/panel called logcat where everything is logged. When your app is force closed, a stacktrace is logged. Copy that and paste it here

Comment: You need to call the `open` method before `return mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);` to initialise your `mDb` object.

Comment: but android logcat not seen in my android studio, so when an application to force close no error message on my logcat, why is this happening? @0xDEADC0DE

Comment: add your logcat @adi

Comment: no force close but after the data added data is not stored in sqlite @PrerakSola

Comment: where are you calling open() method ?

Answer (score 1):

You only pass 1st parameter null in createPemain().

RId field not found in your insert query.
Try it....

That's help you.